# Sscanf ignoring date '-' in date string

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

im having trouble when i try to validate the info of a date string
the code is

```
  char date[] = "1990-01-01";

  sscanf(date, "%d %d %d", &year, &month, &day)
  printf("%d-%d-%d", year, month, day);   

  //expected 1990-01-01
  // actual output 1990--1--1
```

its taking the '-' char as a minus for the month and day, how can i ignore it when taking the value? 
i tried using %*- but it ignored the whole number input
thanks in advance

Comment: Does `"%d %d %d"` match `"1990-01-01"`?

Comment: Im parsing the values into 3 integers and just then printing the result to see if it works @NathanOliver

Comment: I'll ask again, does `"%d %d %d"` match `"1990-01-01"`?  Is there is difference between one string and the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use sscanf conversions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char date[] = "1990-01-01";

    char year[4];
    char month[2];
    char day[2];
    char m1[1];
    char m2[1];
    
    sscanf(date, "%[^-]%[-]%[^-]%[-]%s", year, m1, month, m2, day);
    printf("%s %s %s \n", year, month, day);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution says:

```
gcc -o vd -Wall -pedantic -Wextra  vd.c
./vd
1990 01 01
```

Here is a better program that allows to test on the command line with more input checks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char year[4];
    char month[2];
    char day[2];
    char m1[1];
    char m2[1];
    int rc;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: vd YYYY-MM-DD\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    rc = sscanf(argv[1], "%4[0-9^-]%[-]%2[0-9^-]%[-]%2[0-9]", 
                             year, m1, month, m2, day);
    if (rc == 5)
        printf("%d %d %d \n", atoi(year), atoi(month), atoi(day));
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect date format\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution says:

```
./vd 1990-01-01
1990 1 1 
./vd 1990-12-12
1990 12 12 
./vd 1990-01
Incorrect date format
./vd 1990-ab-13
Incorrect date format
```

Here is a improved version that takes into account @rici comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        char year[4];
        char month[2];
        char day[2];
        int rc;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: vd YYYY-MM-DD\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    rc = sscanf(argv[1], "%4[0-9]-%2[0-9]-%2[0-9]", 
                             year, month, day);
    if (rc == 3)
        printf("%d %d %d \n", atoi(year), atoi(month), atoi(day));
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect date format\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./vd 1990-01-02
1990 1 2 
./vd 1990-12-12
1990 12 12 
./vd 1990-01
Incorrect date format
./vd 1990-db-13
Incorrect date format
./vd 1990--01-02
Incorrect date format
```

Comment: What's the point of using `%[-]` instead of just `-`? If the user enters `1990--01-02`, then the first `%[-]` will match both dashes, but since the result will be a buffer overrun on `m1`, I don't think that can be seen as an advantage.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have modified my code. Thanks.

Comment: And `[0-9^-]`? `%4[0-9]` means "up to four digits". `%4[0-9^-]` means "up to four (digits or `^` or `-`)". It doesn't mean "excluding dash", which isn't necessary since `-` is not in `0-9` and is therefore excluded.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have modified my code. Thanks again.